# Is it possible to run SharePoint 2013 on SQL Server using Compatibility Level 120

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sql-server-2016

I need to migrate a SQL Server 2014 instance supporting SSAS/SSRS and SharePoint 2013 to SQL Server 2016. Unfortunately, I won't be able to have separate instances.
I've read that SharePoint 2013 isn't compatible with SQL Server 2016 but can't find if running it in Compatibility Level (120) is possible.

I would really appreciated some feedback if you have tested this setup.

Thank you very much for your support.

Best Regards